# Common Error Dialog with Navigation Component Android

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment, android-jetpack-navigation

My app is applying SingleActivity approach. So I'm using Navigation library in Jetpack Component.
For each Fragment I have to do error handling such as API response error so the common dialog ( ErrorFragmentDialog) will be shown.

How can I apply ErrorFragmentDialog with Navigation component and how to define the navigator or action in `navigation.xml` class ?